# How to archive iOS notifications?

Tags: ios, notifications

I'd like to record/save my iOS notifications (e.g., games and apps) as they come in as part of a statistics project, and would prefer to have them automatically recorded rather than taking manual screenshots. (Ideally, I'd like to pull them into IFTTT and then push them to a Google Spreadsheet.) Some apps may let me switch the notification method in-app, but that may also change the frequency of the notification, and in any event, it won't work across all apps and I'm looking to track the phone notification frequency. Is there some way to do this without jailbreaking? If I were to somehow push the notifications to macOS, is there a method for automatically recording them on the computer? If the version matters, I'm on the latest iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Due to iOS restrictions, apps can't read notifications. This means you can't run an app to automatically gather notifications without jailbreaking.

Answer (score -2):

i hope use the function,too. I found the function in IFTTT, setuping it but never run. I am not sure it is only run in Andriond.

https://ifttt.com/applets/eLqFf5Ev-save-notifications-from-all-of-your-apps-to-a-google-spreadsheet

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the link you provided will solve the problem.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Answer (score -3):

1.Launch the Settings app on your iOS.
2.Tap on Mail, Contacts, Calendars.
3.Tap on any of your accounts that you want to use archive options with under the Accounts section — if you're using iCloud mail, scroll to the bottom instead and tap on Mail under Advanced and skip to step 5.
4.Tap on Account at the top.
5.Tap on Advanced at the bottom.
6.Under Mailbox Behaviors, make sure you have options set for Deleted and Archived boxes to where you want the

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for. They asked to archive/store all iOS notifications. This is how to archive emails and completely unrelated.